# how to end cocos2d game and remove childs?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am writing as follows

```
  [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
```

the first line will remove all children, and will show blank screen, but yet at back end it works, so I used second line, but as I do use second line, it shows backgroud (ccspirit) and last kids again,

what should I do ?

I want to end current game and go to a method in AppDelegate for starting new game, what should I do, it is cocos2d game,

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to just to recreate your game scene: create new scene and replace the old one.

Comment: Yeah just replace the scene with a different one.  Cleanup is handled automatically (for the most part).

Answer (score 0):

you may find use full from the following link's questation

https://stackoverflow.com/q/6188789/730776

good luck

Comment: it is just a question, with no answer

Comment: question is the answer dude  i have edit  answer in a question

Comment: @priya what problem you are facing??